# Flex mobile wrap html page

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, flex-spark

I'm trying to write an AIR application to be deployed on a mobile device.

I have an HTTPS website that I go to and log in using a browser.  I can view things in my account, etc.

I want to use my AIR app instead of the HTTPS website.  Can I "wrap" or "skin" an html site using AIR?

So I'm looking at StageWebView, URLRequest, URLLoader.

I need to POST things like username, password, and other things.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

See [ExternalInterface on AS3 reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) that you can use to call Javascript-functions on your site.

You can show HTML content with [mx:HTML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html)

If all you need to do is POST or GET, look into [HTTPService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna have a look at the StageWebViewBridge, it has some extended features compared to the default StageWebView
http://code.google.com/p/stagewebviewbridge/

We wanted to use it in a project but ended up in implementing the URL based communication on our own. BUt you should give it a try, mabye it works for you.